The Electronic Electroscope breadboard is not working
Firstly, It's my first time using a breadboard or any electronic components.
I am trying to copy this electronic electroscope circuit from this site. Here is the image of the circuit 
And this image is what i have made, for knowledge i replaced C2 and C4 wirh a 100Picofarrad capacitor as i didnt have 0.1Micro ones.

The two jumper black wires are connected to the sensors.Now I've tried to operate this circuit with 6 Volts as indicated it didnt light up,So how can I know the where is the problem and if someone have any info please help. Thanks in Advance!

There is no possible way this can be hooked up on a breadboard and work as intended. (Even assuming the schematic is well designed.) You might be able to leave some of the circuit on the solderless breadboard. But not all of it. Instead, perhaps follow the construction approach shown in the article. You will have a better chance that way.

Why do you have another account? Why didn't you include this information in your last post? And what do you mean that it's not working? I gave you some helpful advice on how to wire everything from your last post.

@Colin That's my friend's account, I have already corrected the things you mentioned, Thanks for your help but it's still not working, hopefully when i bring the 2 missing capacitors it will work.

@OMARGOGT - Hi, There are problems with both you & your friend posting about the same project (it seems to be the same actual breadboard, judging by the component types & locations common between the images): (a) since the questions overlap, you both risk having questions closed as duplicates (and perhaps annoy people here); (b) the accounts could appear to be multiple accounts by one person, which has a whole set of restrictions itself - breaking any of those restrictions can have consequences. || I recommend just one of you posting from now on.


i replaced C2 and C4 wirh a 100Picofarrad capacitor as i didnt have 0.1Micro ones.

0.1 uF = 1000 x 100 pF
That is, you substituted capacitors that are 1000 times smaller than the design specifies. That alone is likely to doom your circuit to failure, even if it were implemented on a PCB rather than a solderless breadboard.
